# Granting access to users to run specific SQL jobs that runs SSIS packages

Tags: sql-server-2016, security, sql-server-agent, ssis-2016

We need to grant a couple of users access to run only specific SQL jobs that runs SSIS packages. Is there a solution that can be used to accomplish this?

Comment: @LowlyDBA - It is not what I am looking for. SQL jobs can belong to other users but they should be able to run that w/o any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a stored procedure that uses [sp_start_job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) and grant the execute permission on the stored procedure to the necessary users.  The stored procedure can use EXECUTE AS to elevate its permissions so that it can start the job even though the users don't have permission to start the job.